# Python doesn't find MEEP package under Windows

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, meep

I have an issue installing python meep under Windows 10 using cygwin. I installed meep using the following tutorial: [Tutorial](https://novelresearch.weebly.com/installing-meep-in-windows-8-via-cygwin.html)

I have python 3.5 installed on my machine, and actually I read that meep should already have been installed as python package on my machine, and that python should find it (using the usual import command), which is not the case.

So my questions are:

1) How can I be sure that I have the meep module installed on my machine?

2) Is meep only accessible via Cygwin?

Comment: the tutorial shows some misunderstanding about cygwin, however you need to clarify what you did and where is the problem. We can not guess what is happening on your computer

Comment: After following the tutorial, I tried to import meep while using python, receiving the following error message: ImportError: No module named 'meep'. What else should I specify to clarify my problem ?

Comment: Have you compiled and installed `harminv` and `libctl` ? Have you compiled and installed meep ? Have all 3 passed `make check` ?

Comment: Yes, and they all passed the make check.